# how to add a QListWidgetItem on top of the QListWidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I am trying to create something like a layer editor that you normally see in most of the image editor softwares, and for this I need to add the new layers on the top of the `QListWidget`, the code that I'm currently trying is this one:

```
def new_layer(self):

    layer = Layer(layer_name="Layer %d" % self.number_of_layers)
    layer_item = QListWidgetItem(self)
    layer_item.setSizeHint(layer.sizeHint())

    if self.number_of_layers % 2 == 0:
        layer_item.setBackground(Qt.darkGray)
    else:
        layer_item.setBackground(Qt.gray)

    self.setItemWidget(layer_item, layer)
    self.insertItem(0, layer_item)

    self.number_of_layers += 1
```

even after inserting the `QListWidgetItem` in the row 0, when the new layer is added it is displayed beneath the first layer that was previously created. What could I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html#QListWidgetItem):

> **QListWidgetItem::QListWidgetItem(QListWidget * parent = 0, int type =
>   Type)**
>
> Constructs an empty list widget item of the specified type with the
>   given parent. If parent is not specified, the item will need to be
>   inserted into a list widget with `QListWidget::insertItem().`
>
> This constructor inserts the item into the model of the parent that is
>   passed to the constructor. If the model is sorted then the behavior of
>   the insert is undetermined since the model will call the '<' operator
>   method on the item which, at this point, is not yet constructed. To
>   avoid the undetermined behavior, we recommend not to specify the
>   parent and use `QListWidget::insertItem()` instead.

From the above it is concluded that you should not pass the parent to the `QListWidgetItem`, so your code should look like the following:

```
def new_layer(self):

    layer = Layer(layer_name="Layer %d" % self.number_of_layers)
    layer_item = QListWidgetItem() #remove self
    layer_item.setSizeHint(layer.sizeHint())

    if self.number_of_layers % 2 == 0:
        layer_item.setBackground(Qt.darkGray)
    else:
        layer_item.setBackground(Qt.gray)

    self.insertItem(0, layer_item)
    self.setItemWidget(layer_item, layer)


    self.number_of_layers += 1
```

Comment: I've done only a single change in your answer to make it work properly, I've swapped the `self.setItemWidget(layer_item, layer)` line  with the `self.insertItem(0, layer_item)` line, and now it is working the way it was expected, thanks for your answer